Force dpkg-buildpackage to specify exact dependencies for some packages?
I'm building an app that depends on Qt6 and by default dpkg-buildpackage generates a >= dependencies for shlibs dependencies I didn't explicitly specify . So specifying:
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}

Causes:
$ dpkg-query --show -f '${Depends}' mypackage
... qt6-base (>= 6.7.2), ...

The problem is that Qt requires the exact specific version that the app was built against in order to run. If the system has qt6-base version 6.8.0 installed, my app will install but will fail to run - how can I prevent that?
I don't want apt to update my app until I have a version that explicitly supports the exact version of Qt that is available on the system (and/or prevent updating Qt until I have released an appropriate version).
I know I can add manual explicit dependencies for each and every Qt package I depend on - and then update the version manually every time I build with a new Qt version - but this is going to be so much trouble. I would expect there would by an option of something like "for packages that have the text 'qt' in their name, use a = dependency instead of a >=".

Why does it fail to run with 6.8?

I'm actually not 100% sure why Qt works like that, but if I try to run the app with a system Qt different than the one I compiled the app against, I get the error "Cannot mix incompatible Qt library". To the best of my knowledge this is an internal mechanism in Qt to prevent a library upgrade without the app being recompiled, but I'm not sure why someone thought it's a good idea.

There’s no way to force dpkg-shlibdeps to generate strict dependencies rather than the more typical “≥” dependencies, other than specifying strict dependencies explicitly in the relevant symbols file. The Qt packages do define such strict dependencies, as alternative dependencies:
| libqt6core6t64 #MINVER#, qt6-base-private-abi (= 6.7.2)

However these are only used for binaries directly referencing private API symbols with a Qt_6_PRIVATE_API version (the “1” at the very end of that line instructs dpkg-shlibdeps to use alternative dependency 1 instead of the main dependency).
I’m not aware of a way to make use of this automatically in your package, at least not without using private APIs which would be a bad idea. But you can use the ABI package yourself, manually, with a single explicit dependency on the appropriate ABI version:
Depends: qt6-base-private-abi (= 6.7.2)

The advantage of this over manually specifying strict dependencies on all the appropriate library packages is that the dependency will only be broken when the ABI changes. Adding strict dependencies to all the library packages would mean that any update to those packages, including ones which maintain the ABI, would require you to update your package.
